# A Persistent Navigation Drawer with toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, navigation-drawer

I have search a lot but manage the Navigation easily but at this time need to Implement [Persistent Navigation Drawer.](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior)

Please let me know how to implement Persistent Navigation Drawer

[image]